# Creating a column with lookup from another table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table of sales from multiple stores with the value of sales in dollars and the date and the corresponding store.

[image: input table]

In another table I have the store name and the expected sales amount of each store.

[image: lookup table]

I want to create a column in the main first table that evaluates the efficiency of sales based on the other table..

In other words, if store B made 500 sales today, I want to check with lookup table to see the target then use it to divide and obtain the efficiency then graph the efficiency of each store.

Thanks.

I tried creating some measures and columns but stuck with circular dependencies

I expect to add one column to my main table to an integer 0 to 100 showing the efficiency.

[image: output table]

Comment: Would you please share samples of your tables - their columns, and at least a few rows of sample data, as well as the code you have tried, and a mock-up of your expected output.

Comment: Why are there duplicates in the store table? for a relationship, you need unique values in the lookup table.

Comment: they are duplicates for different time of sale.. but assume there is no duplicates

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the two tables. In the query editor go to `Merge Querires > Merge Query As New`. Chose your relationship (match it by the column `StoreName`) and merge the two tables. You will get something like this (just a few of your sample data):

```
 StoreName  ActualSaleAmount  ExpectedAmount
     a            500               3000
     a            450               3000
     b            370               3500
     c            400               5000
```

Now you can add a calculated column with your efficency:

```
 StoreName  ActualSaleAmount  ExpectedAmount  Efficency
     a            500               3000       500/3000
     a            450               3000       450/3000
     b            370               3500       370/3500
     c            400               5000       400/5000
```

This would be:

```
Efficency = [ActualSaleAmount] / [ExpectedAmount]
```